# checking elements is in a set in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy so any help is appreciated. But I am curious how array handles set in python.

This is my code but it doesn't work as expected.
I am trying to filter elements that are not in my set.

```
new_mask = np.where(np.isin(mask, my_set), 1, 0)
```

Because for my understanding, searching in a set is more efficient than in a list due to hashing. But I found this in the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html). I am wondering why it doesn't work?

> Because of how array handles sets, the following does not work as expected:
>
> ```
> >>> test_set = {1, 2, 4, 8}
> >>> np.isin(element, test_set)
> array([[False, False],
>       [False, False]])
> ```
>
> Casting the set to a list gives the expected result:
>
> ```
> >>> np.isin(element, list(test_set))
> array([[False,  True],
>       [ True, False]])
> ```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: From that page: _"If test_elements is a set (or other non-sequence collection) it will be converted to an object array with one element, rather than an array of the values contained in test_elements. This is a consequence of the array constructor’s way of handling non-sequence collections. Converting the set to a list usually gives the desired behavior."_